# How can I track and plot the lowest price since entry of a short position?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to track the low price since entry for my short positions as I have done with the high price for long positions. For some reason the reverse code does not work with shorts.  The long/high plots fine. with different variations to my code I get a flat '0' plot or I get a low that retraces up from the low point.  I basically want to set a trail retracement level where I could stop out of deals that don't quite reach TP% before retracing.

This is the basic code to generate the plot.  Long works fine however this short version and other variations have not worked.  They either retrace with the price increasing rather than showing the lowest point or they plot '0'.  The plot for long and short_entry price works fine, so the other code is initialising the start point correctly.

```
var float high_price_since_entry = na
high_price_since_entry := math.max(long_entry_price, nz(high_price_since_entry[1]), high)
var float low_price_since_entry = na
low_price_since_entry := math.min(short_entry_price, nz(low_price_since_entry[1]), low)
```

Comment: Please format the code in a markdown code block, so it is readable.

Comment: There is no error in these four lines of your code. Share your complete code to help you.

Answer (score 1):

the `low_price_since_entry` variable is being initialized as `na` (not a value) and is only updated when a new short position is entered. This means that if no short position has been entered, the value of `low_price_since_entry` will remain `na`. Plus , if a short position is entered, the value of `low_price_since_entry` will be set to the minimum value of `short_entry_price`, `low_price_since_entry[1]`, and `low` on each bar, but it will not be updated if the price moves higher.

Try modifying your code to only update the value of `low_price_since_entry` when a new short position is entered and when the current low price is lower than the previous value of `low_price_since_entry`.

```
var float low_price_since_entry = na
if (in_short_position)
    low_price_since_entry := min(nz(low_price_since_entry[1]), low)
else
    low_price_since_entry := na
```

value of `low_price_since_entry` is only updated when a new short position is entered (`in_short_position` is true) and when the current low price is lower than the previous value of `low_price_since_entry`. When a short position is not active, the value of `low_price_since_entry` is set to `na`.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, the initial value of `low_price_since_entry` is na, so `nz(low_price_since_entry[1])` will return 0.

As `math.min` returns the lowest value, `math.min(short_entry_price, nz(low_price_since_entry[1]), low)` will return 0 too.
(Assuming `short_entry_price` and `low` are greater than or equal to 0.)

That means `low_price_since_entry := math.min(...)` adds 0 to `low_price_since_entry`. And from then on your function will keep adding zeros.

Try using `nz(low_price_since_entry[1], 1e15)` instead (or some other huge number resembling positive infinity). It replaces na not with 0 but with a value that won't interfere with your `math.min(...)`.

```
low_price_since_entry := math.min(short_entry_price, nz(low_price_since_entry[1], 1e15), low)
```

I didn't test this code, so you'll have to check it yourself.

Comment: thanks for your answers:  i ended up using:                                                                         
var float lowest_price = na

if strategy.position_size < 0 and in_short_trade
    lowest_price := low_price_since_entry > 0 ? math.min(low_price_since_entry, low) : low
    low_price_since_entry := lowest_price
else
    lowest_price := na
    low_price_since_entry := na